# LINQ - Compare two lists of my model that share a property who's value is not equal

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model that contains string properties and in my application I've created two collections of those models by selecting files and reading data in them. I have a Source collection and a Target collection of type `LayerModel`. Each layermodel represents a layer from the drawing file selected by the user, and has properties for each of the pertinent settings I am trying to play with.

The model looks like this:

```
public class LayerModel : IEquatable<LayerModel>
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string OnOff { get; set; }

    public string Freeze { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public string Linetype { get; set; }

    public string Lineweight { get; set; }

    public string Transparency { get; set; }

    public string Plot { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use LINQ to compare those models to produce a list of objects from the target collection who's particular property value is not equal to the source collection.

I have `List<LayerModel> SourceDrawingLayers` and `List<LayerModel> TargetDrawingLayers`. The other day I had a similar question regarding this application and I'm able to produce a collection where every single model with any difference at all is added, and that's great, but now I need to drill down and get specific differences.

This is what I've tried. The first line I am posting here returns nothing, where OnOff is the property I am trying to compare:

```
List<LayerModel> onOffMismatch = TargetDrawingLayers.Where(c => !SourceDrawingLayers.Any(d => c.OnOff == d.OnOff)).ToList();
```

I thought I had an issue with the logic so I tried to reverse it and changed the method to:

```
List<LayerModel> onOffMismatch = TargetDrawingLayers.Where(c => SourceDrawingLayers.Any(d => c.OnOff != d.OnOff)).ToList();
```

This returns every single layer from the TargetDrawingLayers collection.

I realize now that I need to run the following comparison:

Look at all the layers in the TargetDrawingLayers list, find any SourceDrawingLayer whose `Name` property has the same value, then compare the `OnOff` property. If the property is different, I will add it to a List. As a bonus, if a Target layer is not found in the source colleciton, add that to separate `ExtraLayers` List.

Can anyone help out with that?

Comment: If the lists are in the same order and have the same number of elements you can use `Zip` to zipper them together. But why do you keep them separate if you know they correspond? Why not `List<(LayerModel source, LayerModel target)>` using a list of pairs?

Comment: @Ian Mercer, I didn't even know that was possible. I guess that might be an easier approach. Assuming I had a list of sources and targets, how might I go about running the comparison that I need?

Comment: Oh and to the Zip, they won't have the same number and I can't guarantee they'll be in the same order.

Comment: Take a look at `join` or `groupjoin` then.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll experiment with the idea of creating a single list of pairs. Once I do that though I'll be back to my original quandary of how to write a statement that gives me only the targets whose given property does not have the same value from the same item in the source collection. Oh and happy Thanksgiving everyone!